# Regex to validate numbers

Tags: regex

Hi I am creating a regex to have:

- Numbers starting with `02` or `+612`
- Can have spaces
- Numbers starting with `02` to have 10 digits in total excluding space
- Numbers starting with `+612` to allow `+` and 11 digits excluding space
- For numbers starting with `+612`, replace `+61` with `0`

Currently, I created

```
^(\+612)\d{8}$
```

Can anyone help me or suggest me how can I add the above validations in the regex.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `^(?:\+61|0)(2(?:\s*\d){8})$` and also you can replace it easily.

Comment: If after check you're replacing `+61` with `0`, can't you replace it before check and match only numbers starting with `02` with total 10 digits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have an alternation that starts matching at two points and do the replacement afterwards:

```
^ *(?:0 *2|\+ *6 *1 *2)(?: *\d){8} *$
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/a6bx9T/1)

JS code:

```
if (/^ *(?:0 *2|\+ *6 *1 *2)(?: *\d){8} *$/.test(phoneNumber)) {
    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace(/^ *\+ *6 *1/, 0);
}
```